# CodeIgniter 2 my_router.php database connection

Tags: php, codeigniter

How I can start a conection inside `core/my_router.php`?
If I try this:

```
$this->db->query();
```

it returns an error.

Is it correct to do this or does CodeIgniter have another method to do this? I have the controller inside a field table row and I need to execute a query to recover it and load the correct controller.

The error is:
Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Call to a member function query() on a non-object I think thar the method ->db is not valid inside core/ diretorie only in controllers directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Router class is loaded before the CI instance is available which is why you can't use `$CI =& get_instance()` and `$CI->db->query()`.  Calling `$this->db->query()` and similar methods will only work inside your controllers, models, and views (see [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html)).

Here is a thread from the CodeIgniter forums that provides a solution to your problem however it is for version 1.7.2 of the framework so you will probably need to make some modifications.  Keep in mind you will be editing core files so use caution.

[SOLUTION: Database Class / get_instance() in Router.php](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/177130/)

Comment: this is interesting, but it seems odd, I think just being a rookie I'm doing something wrong. As would you do? I can make some generic controller that could act router and all other drivers or something similar?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  The section in the user guide on routing might be of some help.  http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html